# Frequency count using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, word-frequency

I am trying to count word frequency in Pandas dataframe. However, I get a different result when I use a specific word (for instance, labour) to find the frequency of its use and another sum of word count for the same word when I try to find the most frequent words in the whole dataset.

My data looks like this:

```
    text
0   good luck kicked first game hope get
```

I use the following codes to find the most frequent words by both specific words and a list of words:

To look for the word labout in the dataset-

```
df.text.str.count("labour").sum()
741
```

To look for the 2 most common words in the dataset

```
import collections
collections.Counter(" ".join(df["text"]).split()).most_common(2)
[('labour', 650),
 ('today', 473)]
```

Any idea why I might get different results for the same words?

Comment: We really cannot reconstruct your error unless you actually give us the dataframe you're dealing with.

Comment: Try seeing if whole word counts are different: `df.text.str.count(r"\blabour\b").sum()`

Comment: @cs95 The whole word counts seem to be the same.

Comment: @rayryeng The dataframe contains a set of tweets which I first process using bs4, lower case and then remove stopwords ```df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in stop_words]))```

Comment: `" ".join(df["text"]).split()` will [split on whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) here, so `collections.Counter` would have separate counts for e.g. 'labour-intensive', 'labour.' ... `[k for k in yourcounter if "labour" in k]` to see what you missed.